# recasting floats to ieee754 representation in gdb

Tags: python, linux, shell, gdb

Hi I'm playing with following, I'd like to convert between IEEE754 representation and decimal float in Linux shell. The only way I've found is:

```
gdb --batch -ex "print/x (float *) ( (float) 1234.567 )"

gdb --batch -ex "print/f (float *) 0x449A5225"
```

But it doesn't work for double and long double ("Invalid cast"), also gdb also truncates values greater then 32bit, so double and long double.

Is there some gdb expert to help?

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own solution, with Python:

```
# python -c 'import struct; print "%#x" % struct.unpack("I", struct.pack("f", 1234.567))'
0x449a5225

# python -c 'import struct; print "%#x" % struct.unpack("Q", struct.pack("d", 1234.567))'
0x40934a449ba5e354

# python -c 'import struct; print "%f" % struct.unpack("d", struct.pack("Q", 0x4094b2449ba5e354))'
1324.567000

# python -c 'import struct; print "%f" % struct.unpack("f", struct.pack("I", 0x449a5225 ))'
1234.566895
```